boolean Modifier problema (v4.1)
Can anyone tell me how to get the boolean modifier to work. I have enabled it in preferences / add-ons but when ever I apply it I get an error message that reads
Modifier is disabled, skipping apply? Any help is appreciated.

Would you mind to show at least one screenshot of what you are trying to do and the settings of the modifier?

Yes I'm trying to subtract one mesh from another, I think that's supposed to be the Difference modifier?

I cant seem to post screen shots, Sorry for being a bit useless. :(

Maybe look at this first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post Then edit your question and add some. Don't use photos taken of the screen.

Hell, John, welcome to BSE. Could you also clarify which tool you are talking about, please? (I ask, because the Boolean modifier doesn't need to be enabled in preferences.. maybe you mean BoolTool? )

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149437/boolean-modifier-disabled-in-blender-2-8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62301/how-to-fix-modifier-is-disabled-skipping-apply-error
